# symfony 2 - Attempted to call an undefined method named "findBy" of class "testBundle\Entity\test"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I can't get data out of the database. Here's the code:

```
$testRepository= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('testBundle:test');
    $potds = $testRepository->findBy(
        array(),
    );
```

Here's the entity class:

```
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="testBundle\Entity\test")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class test
{ /* ... */ }
```

Here's the code of the Repository:

```
namespace testBundle\Entity;

/**
 * TestRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class testRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
}
```

I get this error message: symfony 2 - Attempted to call an undefined method named "findBy" of class "testBundle\Entity\test"

Inserting data with Doctrine works, so there should be everything right with the Entity.

Comment: Please provide the code and path of the Repository

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have incorrect repository class definition:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="testBundle\Entity\test")
```

Should be:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="testBundle\Entity\testRepository")
```

For now this code:

```
$testRepository= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('testBundle:test');
```

is returning entity class, not repository.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition for the repositoryClass is wrong

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="testBundle\Entity\test")
```

doesn't provide the full path and class name.

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="testBundle\Entity\testRepository")
```

you need to provide the full path and class name, so that Symfony is able to get the correct route.